# Passing objects to events jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this example I'm trying to iterate over the properties of an object that's passed to a click handler, but I am getting unexpected results.
[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/UGGRf/) the fiddle

So with a JS script like

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
        {

            Label = function (name, toDate, fromDate)
            {
                this.name = name;
                this.toDate = toDate;
                this.fromDate = fromDate;
            }

            lbl = new Label('John', 'Today', 'Yesterday');


            $('#btnSubmit').click(function ()
            {
                for (var i in lbl)
                {
                    console.log(i);
                }
            });
            $('#btnSubmit2').click(function (Label)
            {
                for (var i in Label)
                {
                    console.log(i);
                }
            });
        });
```

Why can't I pass an object in the function of a click event and iterate over its properties instead of using the forin loop like I did in the `btnSubmit` example?

Comment: Your numbered questions are hard to understand, even if your global problem seems clear.

Comment: How would you possibly get the Label in the `btnSubmit2` handler? because you name the variable `Label`? it's just the parameter name...

Comment: @dystroy edited for what's most pressing for me.

Comment: @NDM mixing ideas of C# and JS, I guess.  I thought maybe there was some sort of reflection magic that might happen :)

Comment: I hope it's a reference to Type hinting, because if naming a variable invokes reflection I'm very sorry for all C# developers... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback is always called with the event as argument. When you write `click(function(Label){` you only give that event variable the name `Label` (thus shadowing your outside constructor).

But you can access the variables defined in the outer scope, so what you want is probably

```
var lbl = new Label('John', 'Today', 'Yesterday');
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
    for (var i in lbl) {
        console.log(i, lbl[i]); // for example "name", "John"
    }
});
```

Comment: That makes sense when in my second example in the fiddle because there were a lot of properties that I weren't familiar with that I assumed were the event object's properties.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Exactly.

Comment: this is helpful.  My line of thinking what that I could pass the type of object that was clicked on, and have a factory method called to create an object of that type (something like..a span tag for every property, and bind that to the page).  Good to know that I was going down the wrong rabbit hole :)